# Sqlite query to search the longitude and latitude from database

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I am storing the longitude and latitude in database with datatype string(TEXT), suppose by lat value is `37.30408700283523` and long value is `-121.82301333576234`. Maybe sometime lat will have the negative value and long don't have?

My query is :

```
Select * from LatLongTable where lattitude ="37.30408700283523" AND longitude = "-121.82301333576234"
```

but sometimes I am getting the value from the database, but out of 10, 7 times I don't get the value from database.

What is the problem with my query?

Comment: may be your values passed in database does not match to any records

Comment: change you query to `Select * from LatLongTable where lattitude ='37.30408700283523' AND longitude = '-121.82301333576234'`

Comment: @AbhishekSingh then why i am getting data after sometime

Comment: double quotes sometimes conflits within double quotes

Comment: I am not sure what method you are using to set query but have you tried checking `success` and `failure` function and response for the query ?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh query="Select * from "+LatLongTable.TABLE_NAME+" where "+LatLongTable.LAT+" ="+"\'"+lat+"\'"+ " AND "+LatLongTable.LONG+" = "+"\'"+lng+"\'"+" LIMIT 1";  like these query i m giving then also i m not getting

Comment: can you paste your code?